# How to read bad XML with Go

Tags: xml, go

I'd like to use Go to read an XML file. The problem is that it's a bad XML file -- it doesn't conform to the spec.  Here's a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<something abc="1" def="2">
    <0 x="a"/>
    <1 x="b"/>
    <2 x="c"/>
    <26 x="z"/>
</something>
```

My Go program correctly gives an error when trying to read this:

```
$ go run rs.go <real.xml
chardata: '
'
start: name.local='something'
start {{ something} [{{ abc} 1} {{ def} 2}]}
'abc'='1'
'def'='2'
offset=66
chardata: '
    '
XML syntax error on line 3: invalid XML name: 0
exit status 1
```

Here's the little Go program:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

//  <something abc="1" def="2">
type Something struct {
    abc   string `xml:"abc"`
    def   string `xml:"def"`
    spots []Spot
}

//    <0 x="a"/>
type Spot struct {
    num  int    // ??
    xval string `xml:"x"`
}

func main() {
    dec := xml.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
    //  dec.Strict = false      // doesn't help  <0 ...> problem
    //  dec.Entity = xml.HTMLEntity

    for {
        tok, err := dec.Token()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        switch tok := tok.(type) {
        case xml.StartElement:
            fmt.Printf("start: name.local='%s'\n", tok.Name.Local)
            fmt.Printf("start %v\n", tok)
            for _, a := range tok.Attr {
                fmt.Printf("'%s'='%s'\n", a.Name.Local, a.Value)
            }
            fmt.Printf("offset=%d\n", dec.InputOffset())
        case xml.EndElement:
            fmt.Printf("end: name.local='%s'\n", tok.Name.Local)
        case xml.CharData:
            fmt.Printf("chardata: '%s'\n", tok)
        case xml.Comment:
            fmt.Printf("comment: '%s'\n", tok)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a Go expert out there who can help me figure out how to get Go to read this goofy XML file?  Thanks!

Comment: That's not *bad* XML.   It's simply *not* XML.

Comment: To expand on @kjhughes's comment: it doesn't seem like you would be able to use the Go xml package directly here. But you could consider forking the xml package and changing the `isName` function to allow your format, or you need to sanitize the XML first, changing it into valid XML, and then using the Go xml package to do the parsing. Yet another option (probably a good one, depending on how wild your "xml" input is), is to implement your own parser: https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2014/parsers-lexers/

Comment: Thank you for the comments, the suggestions, and the link. All are helpful. Yes, I under-sold the poorness of the XML file... it's sad that it starts with the XML header and then violates the spec. I was hoping that there was a way of using the existing xml decoder (in a stream fashion?) that could be forced to deal with that file. The file is small enough that maybe I'll just regex "<[0-9]" to "<p\1" or something - force the xml 'name' to start with a letter. Thanks again!

Comment: @Herman - if you want to make an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @aMike okay sure, glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer.

It doesn't seem like you would be able to use the Go xml package directly here. But you could:

- consider forking the xml package and changing the `isName` function to allow your format, or
- sanitize the XML first, changing it into valid XML, and then use the Go `xml` package to do the parsing.
- Yet another option (probably a good one, depending on how wild your "XML" input is), is to implement your own parser, as explained on the Gopher Academy blog: [advent-2014/parsers-lexers](http://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2014/parsers-lexers)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to your pointers and suggestions, I was able to read the XML files.
Just rewrite the bad entries to good, and let Unmarshall do its job.
The malformed files I have are small (less than 10k),
so this might not be a good choice if the XML file was 100 MB.

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("<([0-9]+)")
s := re.ReplaceAllString(string(raw), "<splat n=\"${1}\"")

x := Something{Abc: "0"}
err = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &x)
```

Thank you!